# My Tab app doesn't want to appear on the brand page

Tags: facebook, canvas, tabs

I have created a simple app using our clients' err platform.

The Canvas app is viewable - and all the Tab app settings are completed.

When I try to add the tab to the page, it all seems to work fine, but is never visible on the brand page as a shortcut.

The canvas app is: http://apps.facebook.com/oldelpasocompetion

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to post the code at least for people to have a chance to help.

Comment: Are you sure you've actually configured the page tab url and secure page tab url, and that the URL you used is accessible and accepts POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=https://apps.facebook.com/oldelpasocompetion/

Replace YOUR_APP_ID with your app's ID.

This should allow you to add the tab to your fan page